# Socket IO - WSS Throwing error -- remote client, local server

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

Hi I've been trying to figure this out for some time now. It's kind of hard to explain... Ill try and give some background : I'm trying to create a pwa that can work on WAN and LAN for when offline. ---- So I have a client and server, if I host the client and server both locally I'm having no issues I can connect to one another directly and everything, the socket.io and web socket work great. If I host the client and server both on Heroku they work great as well. The problem comes when I host the client on Heroku and the server locally -- which in the application I'm working on I need this. Im able to still connect to the other user if im using the WAN connection portion but if I try to make the connection using LAN it throws errors. I'm not sure what is going on, I'm still fairly new socketio, websockets, etc...   ---- Here is the error I am getting [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0NFI.png). Here are my imports on the server - [imports-server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3MTY.png), how I'm setting up the server - [server setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tT76P.png), how I set up the connection on the client -- [client setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDYmY.png). Sorry if I wasn't clear on my explanation, thank you for help.

Comment: Use code blocks for code/errors/stacktraces.

Comment: Please post your code directly to question, no need of adding extra URLs that can become invalid in future.

Comment: Sorry I will do that for sure.. First post I've ever made, still rusty.